# Program won't remove an item with a variable from a list?

Tags: python, list

I am writing a program where I need to remove products from a list based on  a persons search results. 
Here is a look at my code:

```
 list = [['bike', 50], ['truck', 1000], ['microwave', 10]]
 while True:
    print "----------------------"
    print "Welcome to Craigslist" 
    print "Would you like to:" 
    print "1. Add an item."
    print "2. Find an item."
    print "3. Print the message board."
    print "4. Quit."
    choice = eval(raw_input("Please make a selection."))
    print "-----------------------"

#i took out choice 1 because the problem isn't in choice 1

if choice == 2:
    print "What are you looking for? A bike, microwave, dresser, truck or chicken?"
    itemType = raw_input ("Enter the item type- b, m, d, t, c,:")
    print list
    if itemType == "m":
        itemCost = eval(raw_input("Enter the maximum item cost:"))
        list.remove[('microwave',itemCost)]
        print list
    elif itemType == "d":
        itemCost = eval(raw_input("Enter the maximum item cost:"))
        list.remove('dresser',itemCost)
        print list
    elif itemType == "b":
        itemCost = eval(raw_input("Enter the maximum item cost:"))
        list.remove[('bike' ,itemCost)]
        print list
    elif itemType == "t":
        itemCost = eval(raw_input("Enter the maximum item cost:"))
        list.remove[('truck',itemCost)]
        print list
    elif itemType == "c":
        itemCost = eval(raw_input("Enter the maximum item cost:"))
        list.remove[('chicken',itemCost)]
        print list

if choice == 3:
    print "These are the items for sale on Craigslist."
    print list

if choice == 4:
    quit ("Bye!")

else:
    quit ("Sorry, that's not an option on the menu.")
```

When I try to remove items from the list, based on their name and the input price, I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I had this working earlier where it easily removed `bike` from the list when I entered the price `50` I've tried completely rewriting the lines, switching brackets and parentheses, making `bike` and `bikePrice` equal a variable and then removing that variable- and I can't seem to get it to work. Any input to my amateur coding brain would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please use `int` or `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval`.

Comment: Is your list actually called `list` in your code? Also, `.remove[('bike' ,itemCost)]` isn't how you call a function at all.

Comment: You are using  `list` as a variable name shadowing the python `list` which is not a good idea, you are also trying to index the method reference,  it would be `my_list.remove(['chicken',itemCost])`

Comment: You need () on your remove call and the list is a list of lists rather than a list of tuples, `('chicken',50)` is a tuple, `['chicken',50]` is a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions:

1. change the variable name 'list' to something like 'list1'
2. remove(('something',cost)) is looking to remove a tuple but you have a list so use: remove(['something',cost])

3.use elif instead of multiple if statements

4.'while True:' will keep running the indented block over and over again and not proceed to your if statements.

I think if you make these corrections the code will do what you want it to do. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! that second suggestion got it to work <3